# Use LIKE '%' with integer in SQL

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, datagridview, textbox, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this procedure in SQl Server:

```
create procedure AutoSearchTeamByMobile
@Team_Mobile int
As
select * from Team_Info where Team_Mobile like @Team_Mobile+'%';
```

And I have this code in C#:

```
private void textBoxX4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int tMobile= int.Parse(textBoxX4.Text);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("AutoSearchTeamByMobile", con);
        com.Parameters.Add("@Team_Mobile", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tMobile;
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.SelectCommand = com;
        da.Fill(ds, "Team_Info");
        dataGridViewX1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Team_Info"];
    }
```

I have a list of mobile numbers and they are saved in column called `Team_Mobile` with data type as `int`, one of them start with'711......' another one start with '700......', so now when I write in `textBoxX4` only '7' then all numbers(which start with 711 or 700) should be appears in `dataGridViewX1`, but when I write '71' then only numbers which start with '711' could be appears in `dataGridViewX1`. When I write '70' then only numbers which start with 700 should be appears in `dataGridViewX1`. I did not get what I need, actually I did not see any thing same as I did not do any thing.

My needs, when I write 71 then all records that have 711 in Team_Mobile column should be still appear and the other number should be hide.

But I did it with `Team_Names` and it works because the data type of `Team_Names` is `nvarchar`, but the `Team_Mobile` is `int`.

sql:

```
create procedure AutoSearchTeam
@Team_Name nvarchar (50)
As
select * from Team_Info where Team_Name like @Team_Name+'%';
```

C#:

```
    private void textBoxX1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string t_name = textBoxX1.Text;
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("AutoSearchTeam", con);
        com.Parameters.Add("@Team_Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = t_name;
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.SelectCommand = com;
        da.Fill(ds, "Team_Info");
        dataGridViewX1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Team_Info"];
    }
```

My question is: Is there anyway to replace `%` to use it with integer?

What can I replace `%` to use it with integer to get what I have explained above?

Sorry for my English language.

Comment: good lesson. Phone numbers are only numbers by coincidence. Since you would never be expected to do math with them they are effectively strings and should be stored as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `LIKE` operator is a **string** function.  It requires a string input to test against, and will attempt to automatically convert input values to string (`varchar` or `nvarchar`) before doing the comparison.  Because of this implicit conversion you *can* use if for numbers.

The problem in your code is that you are adding an `int` and a `varchar`.  Try rewriting your stored procedure as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AutoSearchTeamByMobile
    @Team_Mobile int
AS
SELECT * FROM Team_Info WHERE Team_Mobile LIKE CAST(@Team_Mobile AS NVARCHAR) + '%';
```

Casting `@Team_Mobile` to `varchar` will make the `+` operator function correctly, and should give you the results you're after.

---

One style point though...

Storing phone numbers as integers is potentially problematic for various reasons.  At some point you are going to encounter a phone number that can't be stored in the limited range of an integer.  I have thousands of phone numbers in one of my databases that are 16 characters in length, an even when I strip the international dial specifier off them they don't fit in an integer.

Store your phone numbers as `varchar` or `nvarchar` and you'll have a much easier time of things in general.

Comment: BIG THANKS to you dude. You did it man, you are the best one ^_^

Answer (score 5):

For example this

```
SELECT * FROM Team_Info WHERE Team_Mobile LIKE CAST(@Team_Mobile AS NVARCHAR) + '%';
```

Comment: Ah! I didnt understand what he was asking for. :) +1

Comment: @ManyMar what error are you receiving? or what is the indication that it is not working?

Comment: are you sure you have values that match the constraints?

Comment: @paqogomez| YES SURE, I could not upload images to let you understand my needs as well. I need at least 10 reputation to post an image.

Comment: Sorry, I put CAST on wrong variable, I edited that and now it is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I believe you can either via:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Team_Mobile >= @Team_Mobile
```

Above return anything that is greater than 700 (as per your example) without modifying data types.

Or perhaps

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CAST(Team_Mobile AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE @Team_Mobile + '%'
```

Casts the column to a string thus allowing you to use wildcards.

Comment: Not working @_@. Wait I will explain it again with picture examples.

Comment: Sorry I could not upload images they said 'you have to at least 10 reputation to upload images.

Comment: Comparing `>= @Team_Mobile` on an integer field will return **all** rows with a *numeric* value greater than `@Team_Mobile`.  If `@Team_Mobile` is only a few digits, that will give pretty much ever phone number in the table.  You have to convert to (n)varchar to get textual comparisons, of course.

Comment: selected all records that have 700 and 711